# Concatenating list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.7

I have list of dictionaries like this:

```
 [{'X': '10'},
 {'time': '08:34:51', 'load': 28.27, 'memory': 40},
 {'time': '08:34:51', 'load': 28.27, 'memory': 40},
 {'X': '15'},
 {'time': '08:34:51', 'load': 28.27, 'memory': 40},
 {'time': '08:34:51', 'load': 28.27, 'memory': 40}]
```

I need to concatenate the 'X'-dic into the other dictionaries. I simply need the following list of dictionaries:

```
 [{'X': '10', 'time': '08:34:51', 'load': 28.27, 'memory': 40},
 {'X': '10', 'time': '08:34:51', 'load': 28.27, 'memory': 40},
 {'X': '15', 'time': '08:34:51', 'load': 28.27, 'memory': 40},
 {'X': '15', 'time': '08:34:51', 'load': 28.27, 'memory': 40}]
```

what is the simple way of doing this? I must mention that there may be unknown number of such list `{'time': '08:34:51', 'load': 28.27, 'memory': 40}` between the 'X' lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `.update()` method to merge one dict into another:

```
somedict.update(otherdict)
```

To do so with your list, detect the 'source' dicts in a loop and merge those into the others:

```
source = dict()
for mapping in yourlist:
    if 'X' in mapping:
        source = mapping
    else:
        mapping.update(source)
```

Note that I start with an empty dict for the source, in case you don't encounter a dict with the `X` key on the first run through the loop.

The above loop leaves the original sources in the list. If you need to remove these, your best bet is to create a new list with the updated dicts:

```
source = dict()
output = []
for mapping in yourlist:
    if 'X' in mapping:
        source = mapping
    else:
        mapping.update(source)
        output.append(mapping)
```

Comment: thanks, this is the first time I wanted to accept an answer so quickly and got "can not accpect within 3 minutes"